# what does it mean to compress a layer in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Im trying to follow this tutorial here

http://www.psdvault.com/drawing/create-awesome-abstract-nebula-circle-shape-in-photoshop/

And it says

> Compress this layer to a very thins strip

What does that mean and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, "compressing the layer" means to ignore the aspect ratio and make it thinner, but not narrower.

Select the layer, hit Ctrl+T and drag using the mouse.